# How to unzip a unknown zip file in the google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, extract, unzip

I have downloaded a dataset from google colab. But it is neither a folder nor a zip file. It has no extension about it. I downloaded it using `!wget https://sc.link/r7wp` command. But I can't unzip or extract it anyway. Can anyone help me to extract this? See the given screenshot for more explanation

Screenshot

[image: 1]

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look

First try to download it

```
$ wget  https://sc.link/r7w
--2022-08-12 11:59:49--  https://sc.link/r7w
Resolving sc.link (sc.link)... 37.230.233.245
Connecting to sc.link (sc.link)|37.230.233.245|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://sc.link/ [following]
--2022-08-12 11:59:58--  https://sc.link/
Reusing existing connection to sc.link:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 30986 (30K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘r7w’

r7w                           100%[=================================================>]  30.26K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-08-12 11:59:58 (97.0 MB/s) - ‘r7w’ saved [30986/30986]
```

What does unzip think

```
$ unzip -l r7w
Archive:  r7w
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  r7w may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of r7w or
        r7w.zip, and cannot find r7w.ZIP, period.
```

That matches what you are seeing. Let's see if it is actually a zip file.

```
$ file r7w
r7w: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Nope - not a zip file. It's HTML

```
$ head r7w
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><meta name="developers" content="Shadow Dev Team: Kirill Shekhovtsov, Nickolay Galko, Daniil Shemelin, Ivan Ganev, Anatoly Lukasevich, Vlad Vihrov, Alexander Sudarev, Grigory Bezobrazov"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#333333"/><meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="SberCloud - облачная платформа Группы Сбербанк"/><meta property="og:image" content="https://sc.link/sc-link-og.png"/><meta name="yandex-verification" content="0ee928565a89abce"/><meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="q27f48up1g7ono6azi8oe82uwrrysr"/><meta name="google-site-verification" content="6Jsi0B7XAEVcTZTNbbcRG__GhyFIaI-Oej8AiqNMqAg"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://sc.link/logo-192.png"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
```

Comment: I just used the command to extract it:
`!jar xvf r7wp`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using this command.

```
!jar xvf r7wp
```

where `r7wp` is the file name